# datepicker in popup directly open when I click a button?

Tags: windows-phone-8, datepicker, timepicker

As [described](http://q.cnblogs.com/q/42920/) i input a **datepicker** in my xaml file

when i run the page ,datepicker just show like this:

[image]

then I have to tap the datepicker to enter the select page like this :

[image]

***Now***

**I need to directly open the fullscreen datepicker select page when I click a button**

the address give a way that I can just Navigate to the select page,

but I don't know how ?

Comment: When you click *which* button?

Comment: just when I run the phonepage,  then click A button below the datepicker to open the select page...@Toni Petrina

Comment: The round one with the (x)?

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/f846cded-90e8-4859-89c1-d67124b8b532/programatically-launching-datepicker.

Comment: well , let me check it @Toni Petrina

Comment: help！I dont wanna to re-write the datepicker。。

Comment: Have you tried the solution from the link above?

Comment: @Mr.Wrong Did you achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the poster.

i find a solution myself

Override DatePicker class with our custom DatePickerCustom class. Create new class "DatePickerCustom.cs"

```
public class DatePickerCustom : DatePicker
{
    public void ClickTemplateButton()
    {
        Button btn = (GetTemplateChild("DateTimeButton") as Button);
        ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(btn);
        IInvokeProvider provider = (peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider);

        provider.Invoke();
    }
}
```

then in the mainpage.xaml.cs

```
private DatePickerCustom datePicker;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // create datePicker programmatically
        if (this.datePicker == null)
        {
            this.datePicker = new DatePickerCustom();
            this.datePicker.IsTabStop = false;
            this.datePicker.MaxHeight = 0;

            this.datePicker.ValueChanged += new EventHandler<DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs>(datePicker_ValueChanged);

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(this.datePicker);

        }
    }

    void datePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // now we may use got value from datePicker
        TextBlock1.Text = this.datePicker.ValueString;
    }
```

so that when do an action like tap or click, the fullscreen datepicker page will be shown

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     this.datePicker.ClickTemplateButton();
}
```

ps: timepicker can also do the same thing

ps2:[here](http://transoceanic.blogspot.be/2011/08/wp7-create-datepicker-control.html?showComment=1368006743019#c7385407930661977731%22here%22) is the details

@Mario Galván

hope it help u

Comment: Getting btn=null. Can you please help me? I'm working on WP 8.1 silverlight app.

Comment: Button btn = (GetTemplateChild("FlyoutButton") as Button); this will solve button null reference issue.